# How to include all fields from foreign key in django model form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access the fields related to a foreign key from a model form. I have read the docs and it seems I should be able to access these fields with dot notation.  Does what I am attempting make sense? Is there a better way to do this same thing.

html form

```
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.room.room_available }}
{{ form.renter }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    roomNum = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    room_is_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    room_available = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class BookedRoom(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    renter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    end  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Views.py

```
def bookRoomNow(request, pk):
   room = get_object_or_404(Room, pk=pk)

   if request.method == "POST":
      form = BookingForm(request.POST or None)
      if form.is_valid():
         form = form.save(commit=False)
         #this room.instance
         form.room = room
         form.save()
      
         return redirect('room_details', pk=room.pk)
   
   else:
      form = BookingForm()
   
   context= {"form":form}
   return render(request, 'booker/booking_form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

The context variable form you are passing is largely concerned with the form itself - fields,  errors etc.

You can pass the Room model instance itself as a separate context variable:

```
 context= {"form":form, "room":room}
```

And then refer to its fields via dot notation

```
{{ room.room_available }}
```

However, if you want to display the form field itself (eg a HTML input with the current value set if there is one), and the field is included in your form definition,  you can use

```
{{ form.renter }}
```

You can't follow directly from bookingform to room field to another field of the model room because the 'room field' can't be both a literal HTML form field in the booking form and also a model instance of a Room. The use of field in both cases is a little confusing perhaps (and also the bookedroom won't actually exist until after the form is submitted as your view is creating bookings, not editing them!)